# Who will be the Moderator? What attributes should they have?

Tags: discussion, moderation, community-moderators

As you guys know, the Moderators are usually chosen at the end of the Private beta period. Seeing that we have minimum 5 days left, I think it is the perfect time to outline what *we* would like to see in a moderator. A moderator needs to be someone who not only knows arduino inside and out, but also can suggest creative criticism, and who is always can have a positive attitude.

But that isn't everything that would make the perfect moderator. I am wondering what qualities make the *perfect* moderator, be sure to include how important these attributes are!

For example:
Knows Arduino inside and out - Necessary

Comment: *Temporary* moderators are appointed at the end of the Private Beta.  These aren't permanent.  Anyway--I feel it's a little early for this question... it will be fairly obvious who is (and isn't) taking an active interest in the community (asking/answering questions), as well as its governance (meta participation).  Furthermore, moderators are, in general, supposed to be "invisible"--the community is supposed to decide what is on/off topic, the mods are there simply to make sure no one is being rude/inappropriate/getting out of hand.

Comment: @anorton I would argue that the *diamond* should be invisible, not necessarily the user who holds it. Also, in the initial stages, moderators have to be heavily involved as there are not enough users at the needed reputation levels to carry out all the moderation activities needed.

Comment: @AsheeshR eh... maybe "invisible" didn't convey the term I meant.  My point is that Moderators shouldn't take on a "one man army" approach to keeping the site in check--they need to ensure that they are acting as representatives of the community, rather than a ruling class.  But, that's material for a different thread, methinks.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback

Answer (score 6):

Actually, knowing Arduino *too well* is far from  necessary. They should be knowledgeable, yes, but anything more is just a bonus for the community and their efforts should be focussed as such ;-)

What is needed in a community moderator is the ability to communicate clearly and effectively, as well as have the patience to handle all types of members of the community *respectfully*. Also, to function impartially even when faced with difficult situations such as that may happen involving respected members, arguments, flame wars, etc.

Community moderators aren't referred to as *janitors* for nothing. There is a fair bit of work to be done behind the scenes, a lot of which *may* be fairly involved and taxing. The only reward for this effort is seeing the site grow and move towards graduation (which can be rather satisfying :) )

The only thing **necessary** is that the individual should be active and involved in the community through content generation, meta participation, *chat availability*, editing, reviewing and voting (close/reopen). Also, in general the individual should be helpful and guide new members of the community wherever needed.

<sub>Evangelising the community and being a good representative of Arduino.SE wherever the situation may so demand would be great too!</sub>

---

**TL;DR** Moderators should know Arduino.SE and we should know them; nothing else is needed.

Comment: +1 you do look like a good candidate to me.