# Provisional Community Moderator Nominations

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation, community-moderators

We already [decided *some* attributes that the  moderators should have](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46/who-will-be-the-moderator-what-attributes-should-they-have), now let's start actual nomination.

> Actually, knowing Arduino too well is far from necessary. They should
> be knowledgeable, yes, but anything more is just a bonus for the
> community and their efforts should be focussed as such ;-)
>
> What is needed in a community moderator is the ability to communicate
> clearly and effectively, as well as have the patience to handle all
> types of members of the community respectfully. Also, to function
> impartially even when faced with difficult situations such as that may
> happen involving respected members, arguments, flame wars, etc.
>
> Community moderators aren't referred to as janitors for nothing. There
> is a fair bit of work to be done behind the scenes, a lot of which may
> be fairly involved and taxing. The only reward for this effort is
> seeing the site grow and move towards graduation (which can be rather
> satisfying :) )
>
> The only thing necessary is that the individual should be active and
> involved in the community through content generation, meta
> participation, chat availability, editing, reviewing and voting
> (close/reopen). Also, in general the individual should be helpful and
> guide new members of the community wherever needed.

---

### How do you become a provisional moderator for this site?

Soon after the site launches into "public beta," the Community Team will appoint *provisional moderators* from this community until the community is ready to hold its own elections (once it graduates from beta).

---

### What do moderators gain?

> Candidates will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act
> as provisional Moderators until the community holds formal elections
> after the Beta period. Besides the normal abilities of a Moderator,
> they will:
>
> 1. Have access to a special chat room where we will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing.
> 2. Organize the process of selecting the site’s attributes (the [help center], site scope, tags, etc.).
> 3. Rally community support and drive the mission of getting publicity for the site.
>
> Essentially, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for
> anything we can do to help their sites succeed!**

---

### Here's what you should have to be a moderator here:

- Have a decent reputation
- Participate on Meta
- Be well spoken, polite, professional (that includes formatting it with bold and other tags to make it look good and spelling/grammar), and a natural leader.
- **Be trusted.** You'll have some data that a standard user won't. Handel it wisely and follow the TOS and privacy policy of SE.
- Have a decent amount of time (30+ minutes a day has been recommended to *this* site only for "dirty work.")
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Bonus points for:

- Moderator or high-reputation on other sites
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

---

### To nominate (You are encouraged to nominate you and others)

**Please break it down into one section for each item listed below:**

1. Post an answer containing the URLs to the user's **main *and* meta profiles on Arduino.SE**. You can also add links to other profiles or to an Area51 profile. Also, if you
2. Why you think they/you would be a good candidate.
3. If you are nominating yourself, please add a little bit about you, why you would be a good candidate, and if you really have the time and devotion to guide this community, when it's fun, and when it's a pain in the **********.

Post each user as a separate answer, and add multiple answers if you wish to nominate multiple users. Do not make duplicates of questions.

Additionally, if someone nominates *you*, please **edit the answer** to indicate your approval (or declination). If you want to, add a paragraph or two about yourself so we can get to know you.

If you downvote a particular nomination, you are encouraged to **share why** you did so in the comments, though you are not required to do so. Optionally, you may do the same for upvotes.

For more information, see [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

---

### Optional Template:

```
## I'm Nominating: {Username OR "Myself, {UsernameHere}"} ##

**Links:** [Main (1 Rep)](www.example.com), [Meta](www.meta.example.com), [Other Sites Here (100K Rep, Moderator)](www.othersite.example.com)

{Put Flair Here if you want}
*****
I am a good candidate because... I do... I want...
*****
{Optional (remove the "****" above if you aren't doing this): Getting to know you here}
```

Comment: That went by fast. I was gone for 2 days and i missed it.

Comment: @TheDoctor Yes: it was quick because it happens when we go into public beta.

Comment: This is now obsolete because the nominations are over.

Answer (score 6):

### I'm Nominating: Myself, Peter R. Bloomfield

**Links:** [Main (~900 Rep)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/42/peter-r-bloomfield), [Meta](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42/peter-r-bloomfield), [Stack Overflow (~3k Rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2500951/peter-r-bloomfield)

[profile for Peter R. Bloomfield on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2918160.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/2918160)

---

**Why me?**
I believe I'm a good candidate because I have past experience of managing/moderating online communities (mostly forums). I also have an academic background, with a few publications in the computing field, so I can communicate well in writing.

I believe in being civil and respectful, and that we should strive to make newcomers feel comfortable here. I always aim to remain objective in the face of disputes and disagreements. With that said, I know that it's sometimes necessary to take a hard line.

I've been a little hesitant to nominate myself for a moderator role, simply because I'm fairly busy already. Realistically though, I should certainly be able to average at least 30 minutes per day without any difficulty.

---

**More about me**
I'm one of those weird people who somehow still enjoys programming, despite doing it 8 hours a day, 5 days a week. By day, I'm a professional Software Engineer; hardcore C++ is my proverbial bread and butter. My focus as a research/programmer over the past several years has been educational technology and virtual environments.

I've had to do a little embedded systems work at my job, but electronics is mostly just a hobby. I find Arduino to be an excellent platform, because it can provide a fairly gentle introduction to the area, but it's also very capable for more advanced projects.

I should maybe note that there is actually more to my life than just computers. I have other interests too! I'll stop rambling now though. :) If there are any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of experience with coding, but not much with EE. Arduino needs both: can you adjust to make up that gap?

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson experience and knowledge with the subject can be helpful for a moderator and shouldn't be ignored, but you don't have to be an expert on the subject to be a candidate. Judging by Peter's contributions around the site thus far, I think he's a fantastic candidate

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson The EE stuff I've done in my job (and am still doing) is actually a sizeable bare-metal AVR project, interfacing with multiple external systems. It really goes much deeper than I suspect most Arduino.SE visitors are likely to need.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield Sorry I'm just looking at the EE.SE profile of yours... :P

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson I'd completely forgotten that I'd created one! I've never really had to refer to EE.SE as a questioner, and I don't think I have enough to contribute there as an answerer (compared to EE professionals).

Comment: I agree with @AnnonomusPerson that some EE knowledge is essential for any good Arduino.SE moderator. As a measurement, I was looking for good answers from the candidates on SE.EE. If he or she manages to post a few great answers there and not getting beaten up much, I figure the candidate at least know what a great answer is when he or she sees it. While Annonomus Person meets that requirement, his last comment doesn't make him a worthy moderator candidate. While Peter doesn't pass that SE.EE requirement, he's got a good amount of activity in Ar.SE and shows he's nice and fair. My vote is his.

Answer (score 5):

## I'm Nominating: Myself, sachleen

**Links:** [Main (1200+ Rep)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/11/sachleen), [Meta](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11/sachleen)

[image: profile for sachleen at Arduino Stack Exchange, Q&A for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino]

[image: profile for sachleen at Arduino Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino]


[image: profile for sachleen at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

---

I am a good candidate because...

I really want this site to succeed. I started electronics with Arduino and I want to help other people, beginners or otherwise, get off to a good start, too. I'm very active on the site, and I like to think my answers provide a examples of what a "good" answer looks like.

Some examples:

- [Why does my sketch report too many button presses?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/408/why-does-my-sketch-report-too-many-button-presses/411#411)
- [Serial data showing up weird](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/261/serial-data-showing-up-weird/262#262)

I also make an effort to stay on top of the review queue. I have some experience with this from SO, where I have over 1000 edits and hundreds of other review related tasks. I bring over the same habit to Arduino.SE. **I'm on the site every day trying to help wherever I can.**

Check out my [**recent activity**](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/11/sachleen?tab=activity) on the site to see what I'm up to.

---

## Questions & Answers

Ask your questions in the comments and I'll answer them here.

**What sets you apart from the other candidates here?** - Annonomus Person

There are a handful of people here that are just as capable as me and would make excellent moderators. I'm not trying to win votes, I trying to help the site succeed. I will continue to use the tools available to me to make the site a better place, moderator, or not.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson, Thanks! I added a response to your question in my post.

Answer (score 3):

### I'm Nominating: [hichris123](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/35/hichris123)

**Links:** [Main (213 Rep)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/35/hichris123), [Meta](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/users/35/hichris123)

[image: profile for hichris123 at Arduino Stack Exchange, Q&A for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino]

[image: profile for hichris123 at Arduino Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino]
[profile for hichris123 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/3046327.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/3046327/hichris123)

---

I've worked with hichris on several SE-related things under the [Charcoal](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) project, and I have to say that he learns extremely quickly and is fast to understand abstract concepts like moderation. I also really like his [activity](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/35/hichris123?tab=activity) on this site.

---

#### Accept

First off, thanks for nominating me. I'd really like to help this site grow and prosper.

I love Arduinos. I (of course) have one at home, tinker with it, and was very excited to find out this site was launching. I'm active on the Stack Exchange network, on sites like Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, and Space Exploration.

I know quite a bit about moderation from my conversations with mods. Some stuff I don't know; however, I can quickly learn this from the community team and other mods that I know.

I would *love* to guide this community with a firm, but gentle, hand. I see a lot of potential in this site, and would like to guide it so that we can prosper. We have a lot of great content, but would like to make sure that the bad stuff gets closed or removed from the site. I'd also like to participate more in editing posts/tag wikis, retagging, and overall keeping the site clean. I'm also going to be active on meta, helping to guide this site, as well as being active in [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/arduino).

Comment: _Pretend_ for a moment that I am one of those really impatient and annoying users that posts comments everywhere asking for an answer to a question they asked 5 minutes before. How would you respond?

Comment: @SantaClaus Well, in what place? Like in the comments sections of posts? Or in chat? Or in a different place that I'm not thinking of? :P (side note, please ping me with replies... Undo gets the notifications automatically for this, but not me)

Comment: @hichris123 Assume I am that _really_ annoying user that posts **comments** everywhere that say `Please help:  www.stackoverflow.com/link/to/badly/formatted/question/`. How would you respond?

Comment: @SantaClaus That would be an annoying user. ;) So what I'd end up doing is deleting those comments, since they're not relevant to the post. Also, I'd notify the user via chat (mods get this nice thing called superpings, letting you ping people who've never been to chat before) that this behavior isn't allowed, and not to do it again. If it continues... probably a mod message, and maybe suspension, depending on how bad it is, but I'd work with the user in any case.

Comment: @hichris123 Sounds good. Two quick questions: `If you had to compare yourself to a fruit, what would it be and why`, and also `What is your favorite number`. Remember, these are _very_ important questions that determine weather I regret voting for you or not. ;)

Comment: @SantaClaus Is this part of being a mod, being compared to fruit? ;P Um... for fruit probably a grapefruit because I love grapefruits, and they're actually really amazing and interesting. My favorite number: 42, of course. ;)

Comment: We really haven't seen you enough both on main and meta.

Answer (score 2):

### I'm Nominating: [AsheeshR](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/65/asheeshr)

[profile for AsheeshR on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1609527.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1609527/asheeshr)

[image: profile for AsheeshR at Arduino Stack Exchange, Q&A for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino]

---

I think Asheesh is a great candidate because he meets all the criteria specified in the nomination, more specifically, those below:

- He's got a decent reputation
- He participates on Meta
- He's well spoken, polite, professional (that includes formatting it with bold and other tags to make it look good and spelling/grammar), and a natural leader.
- He can be trusted.
- He's already shown that he's got a decent amount of time to dedicate to us (30+ minutes a day has been recommended to this site only for "dirty work.")
- He's got high-reputation on other sites
- He's got Area 51 participation
- He's a member who has already shown an interest or ability to promote our community.
- And he's very knowledgeable about Arduinos.

My vote is his.

---

Thanks for the nomination. I would enjoy working on the site and taking it forward. I participate in a few beta sites which has gotten me a fair bit of experience with regards to *what works*, and *what doesn't*. I am sure that this experience will help in carrying out the work that will be needed.

Comment: [Asheesh is also a moderator on RE.SE](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/189/asheeshr)

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks for the very kind words. This post *almost* made me want to vote for myself :)

Comment: @AsheeshR - Well, you deserve them. Too bad you didn't get elected. I guess the problem was the timing: just like regular questions, those who answer first have higher chances of getting upvoted and accepted. But I'm sure you'll keep acting as a moderator, so we are all winning anyway :D

Comment: @AsheeshR - Since I nominated you, I could't vote for you because the system didn't let me. So I was counting that *you* would vote for yourself and that would count as my vote. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Somebody else voted for you, besides you and me, then.

Comment: @AsheeshR - Next time, you, sir, nominate yourself right when the nomination period opens. If someone nominates you, you make sure you vote for yourself. In elections, every vote counts. You're young so you will have to brag about yourself to get great jobs, so start practicing *ASAP*.

Answer (score 0):

### Hi, I'm Annonomus Person and I'm nominating myself for this community election started by me

(I'm personally voting for `HiChris123`)

**Links:** [Main (452 and Counting Rep)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/220/annonomus-person), [Meta](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/users/220/annonomus-person), [EE (1,235 Repuation)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/18442/annonomus-person)

[image: This is me!]

[profile for Annonomus Person on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1640390.png?theme=dark](http://stackexchange.com/users/1640390/annonomus-person)
[image: profile for Annonomus Person at Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, Q&A for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts]
[image: profile for Annonomus Person at Arduino Stack Exchange, Q&A for developers of open-source hardware and software that is compatible with Arduino]

[image: profile for Annonomus Person at Robotics Stack Exchange, Q&A for professional robotic engineers, hobbyists, researchers and students]


[image: profile for Annonomus Person at Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, Q&A for users and developers of hardware and software for Raspberry Pi]


[Area 51 profile for Annonomus Person http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flair/76333.png?theme=dark](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/76333/annonomus-person)

---

### Why I feel I'm a good candidate (in bullet points for better SEO `:P`):

- I'm fairly active on meta: 6 questions and four answers. **That alone isn't that great, I know.** I'm almost ashamed running for moderator with that. *However*, it's what you can't see that makes me stand out. I [go the extra mile, with 14 edits on one CWiki post](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/31/revisions), trying to make our tagging get off to a good start.
- **I am the only user that has fully participated in any of these sites: Robotics, EE, and RPi.** These three sites are the ones that are almost guaranteed to have scope conflict. Moderators shape the community, and moderators need to be informed. I'm definitely informed.
- I try hard, and ***never*** give up. I *want* this site to succeed. I was the part of the Arduino beta last time, and I was annoyed when it was shut down. I'll do what it takes to get us through beta. I *need* to shape my little corner of the world. It's my calling, my duty, and my responsibility.

> Here’s to the crazy ones. The misfits. The rebels. The troublemakers.
>   The round pegs in the square holes. The ones who see things
>   differently.
>
> They’re not fond of rules. And they have no respect for the status
>   quo. You can quote them, disagree with them, glorify or vilify them.
>
> About the only thing you can’t do is ignore them. Because they change
>   things. They push the human race forward.
>
> And while some may see them as the crazy ones, we see genius.
>
> Because the people who are crazy enough to think they can change the
>   world, are the ones who do.

### I may be a crazy round peg who sees things differently, but that doesn't mean I'm stupid.

- I will rewrite the Arduino engine to use jQuery (just kidding)
- You can eat a waffle if I'm moderator **any time of the day!** MMM waffles... nom nom nom. [image: Waffles... yummy] Waffles... yummy! Unless you like pancakes better.
- I will do a ***full*** cleanup of the tags (already kinda messy but that's natural with any beta)
- I am a grammar and spelling <strike>jerk</strike> <strike>natzi (not to be offensive to anyone, it's an American English thing)</strike> <strike>freak</strike> loving person.

<sub>Read more about me on my *[profile](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/220/annonomus-person)*</sub>

---

### Why I *shouldn't* Be a Moderator*

<sub>*Yes, the first time in recorded history I *did* actually do that in a moderator election.</sub>

- <strike>I prefer pancakes</strike> Not really... no need for all the controversy, @Undo!!! :P
- I haven't ever used moderational tools or had full edit capability (exception: last Arduino beta for editing without approval). However, I adapt quickly.
- <strike>I probably might not always have time to put in 10 hours a day. I'll try to do at least 30 minutes daily to empty the queues. I *do* have a [seven page activity log, though](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/220/annonomus-person?tab=activity). I don't know if I have the patience or time to be in chat 24/7 either, but I'll ***try***.</strike> **I am now the biggest user of [Pin 13 (A.K.A. *Arduino* Chatroom)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/arduino)**.

Despite the above, I feel that I would be a legendary moderator. I have vision, dedication, and perseverance. If *you* elect me, I can almost guarantee that I will make this proposal live. I'm a trustworthy person who *will* make this site succeed. **EDIT:** As time progresses I seem like the more ideal moderator.

<sub>No Arduinos hurt in the making of this.</sub>

Comment: -1 Sorry but your comment on Peter's nomination isn't what I expect from a moderator (I quote: `@Peter Haha I just saw that and none of your answers so far dig into deep electronics so... Oops! –`). You got to be nice and fair to be a decent moderator.

Comment: @Ricardo I was referring to his *[EE Profile](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/28996/peter-r-bloomfield)*. ;) I never intended for it to be rude, but looking back it could be interpreted a few different ways.

Comment: Ok. I'll take back my downvote in appreciation for your retraction. Knowing when to apologize *is* a desired characteristic of a great moderator. Just gotta be *extra careful* with what you write, especially if you want to be a moderator. One lousy comment here and there is ok for regular users but not for mods.

Comment: Nope, can't remove the downvote unless you edit your nomination.

Comment: @Ricardo I updated some numbers... you don't have to remove it though if you don't want to. If you would rather have the others be moderators, I would favor the community being better off than me getting moderator.

Comment: No sweat! I'm sure you'll be a great moderator, as all other folks who were nominated. We all want this site to be the best it can be. I guess that being a mod has it's own learning curve. This was just one step up the ladder.

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks for your support! Note: [there are always mod decisions that aren't supported...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/190823) :D

Comment: Nice try, but he is Jeff Atwood, the StackOverflow and StackExchange founder, mod of the mods. He is [the Dangeon Master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_(TV_series)#Protagonists). He has the luxury of being unpopular sometimes. We don't ;)

Comment: Next will you compare yourself to [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), [the Chuck Norris of SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)? :P

Comment: @Ricardo Yes he is forgiven, but really, [-192 votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949)? That's pushing his luck.

Comment: You can have my vote if you agree to not clutter the site with large pictures of waffles that make answers longer than they rightfully should be.

Comment: @Santa Sorry about that... I was just hungry! :) Anyway, I won't do that. When I add pictures, they are usually relevant (with an exception of this one here).