# Please welcome your new moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderation, community-moderators

First off, thanks to everyone who participated at the [Provisional Community Moderator Nominations](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79/provisional-community-moderator-nominations) meta post.

I may eventually be contacting additional users to fill more moderator slots, but I wanted to get the folks below activated before things really started to take off.

Throughout the beta, we need members from this site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Annonomus Person]
[image: Peter R. Bloomfield]
[image: sachleen]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Yes, almost certainly. At the nomination post alone, there were more great choices than positions available. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My inability to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats to all! I'm sure you'll do a great job!

Comment: That was *quick*! Congratulations to everybody!

Comment: Congratulations, folks! Use your new powers wisely. We'll be watching :D

Comment: Thanks everybody!

Comment: I would be interested in being a Mod. Please contact me so i don't miss another nomination post (i was only gone *2 days*)

Comment: @TheDoctor What does being gone two days have to do with it? It was up for a week. I do however agree that the nomination post should have been more prominent. By the time I saw the post, Peter, Sachleen, and Chris already had so many votes that I had no chance of catching up when I nominated myself.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat - i never saw it until it was over :(

Comment: @TheGuyWithTheHat What are you talking about? It was make [tag:featured] on the 24th, a day after the nominations thread had been posted. This is five days after the nominations thread has been posted.

Comment: @TheDoctor See my comment above this one.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Featured != Always noticed, and it's been a lot longer than five days since it was posted

Comment: @TheGuy I always notice the featured questions, but I also notice things that others don't. :) But I was refering for the five days from when it was posted to when *this* was posted.