# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Arduino's [first moderator election](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Nick Gammon] [image: Anonymous Penguin] [image: Majenko]

They'll be replacing [the existing crew](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

I'd like to take this opportunity to thank the [provisional](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/please-welcome-your-new-moderators) and [pro tem](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/please-welcome-your-new-pro-tem-mods) moderators for stepping into the role and guiding this community to it's first successful election. Great job everyone!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5194091390304256/0).

Comment: Mwahaha!!! The power is mine!!!!  Cower, brief mortals!

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to the team, [Majenko](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/4143/majenko)! I'm sure your enthusiasm for answering questions will also translate into enthusiastic moderating. :)

---

Farewell to [Avamander](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/11529/avamander) - you stepped into the Pro Tempore moderator position when we needed another couple of moderators, in January 2016, and filled the position with competence and grace. I hope we will continue to see you here as a contributor to Arduino Stack Exchange in general.

---

Thanks to everyone who voted for me. I hope to continue moderating in much the same way as I have in the past.

---

Finally, remember moderators are just people too, with their own interests in Arduino. You can always contact us in [the Pin 13 chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/pin-13) if there is something you want to discuss. If necessary we can set up a private chat room if there is something confidential you want to talk about.