# Arduino.SE graduation: will users lose privileges?

Tags: discussion

Arduino.SE is graduating. Woohoo!

When a site graduates the reputation required to earn certain privileges eventually rises. My question is: will users lose privileges earned under beta rep thresholds, as their rep will be below the new thresholds? Are earned privileges kept after graduation?

Comment: This is what happens when you make an overly narrow site for a subcategory of questions which belong on EESE.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - this is what happens *when a site graduates*. You have this "problem" whether or not it is an "overly narrow site" (as you put it). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139432/reputation-privileges-when-a-beta-becomes-a-fully-fledged-site/). Trying to tie this to the sort of questions that might be asked on EE.SE is just a long and irrelevant bow.

Comment: No, Nick, the specific issue is cause by graduating *with too small a user community* which is in turn caused by *having a site with too narrow a mission*.  This is beyond obvious to anyone willing to take an *honest* look - which no doubt will be hard to those who've become caught up in this ill-conceived project to arbitrarily split off a small portion of EESE topics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Privileges do not exist independently of reputation. If your current reputation is below the level that is currently required to perform an action, then you cannot perform that action.

So yes, some privileges will be lost.  But not soon. As the announcement  says:

> Later, the site will still receive a full custom design from one of our staff designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege.

Custom designs take a long time to arrive. There are 8 graduated sites waiting for designs already, and no custom designs shipped so far in 2017, so... there's a good chance that by the time this happens, your reputation will be high enough so you can still close, edit, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I believe that the "full site" privileges will apply once we get the site design (which as Alex said could well be months away).

For reference, here is the current [privileges list](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Compare to the numbers for a full site such as [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

There are 29 users today who would have access to "edit questions and answers" (2000 rep).

One of the reasons why we took a while to graduate was that, [in January 2016](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2310/beta-progress-update-january-2016), the Stack Exchange people noticed that we had very few people with enough privileges to do things like editing.

In the meantime, before we get our site design done, we all have time to increase our reputation. I notice that quite a few people have quite healthy rep levels, even though they only joined around 6 months ago. You could probably expect those to double in the next 6 months.

> Later, the site will still receive a full custom design ...

The word "later" is pretty open. We may well have a year to bump up privileges before the new levels are activated.

Comment: Maybe the SE people are concerned about not having enough people with editing privileges, but I'm far more concerned (qualitywise) about having only 16 users today able to close questions (3,000 rep).

Comment: Yes, but since the rep changes are likely to be 6 months away, there are a number of people (like you) who could double their rep in that time, and reach that threshold. All SE sites which graduate are likely to have similar issues, and they seem to have survived.

Comment: This is fundamentally a demonstration of why Arduino should never have been a distinct site.  The pool of expertise to provide good answers, and the pool of high-rep users already exists on EESE; by creating an Arduino site, questions get shifted to disfunctional backwater and certain notorious curmudgeons on EESE get a migration option / closure excuse they've developed an impressive track record of abusing.

Comment: Perhaps the "notorious curmudgeons" are why people prefer to post here? Arduino is targetted at beginners, some people on EE.SE don't seem to be able to accept that fact.

Comment: Example of a similar thing: [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) vs. [English Language and Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @NickGammon Stack Exchange rules are Stack Exchange rules - same here as on EESE.  Arduino is not only about beginners, and beginners use many things other than Arduino, so the association is illogical, and counterproductive as it artificially divides similar questions which should be being handled together.

Comment: For people concerned about the reputation/privileges issue I'd like to make a suggestion: Make a little more effort to upvote good answers. A big problem I see with this Stack Exchange is that generally the people asking questions have no interest in accepting answers or upvoting. The main way for people to gain reputation here is upvotes from the regulars.